# Sympy/Matlab Plot y=mx, without any numerical value of m

Tags: matlab, matplotlib, plot, octave, sympy

I need to plot `y = m*x` where x ranges from, say 0 to 10. But `m` is a symbolic constant here, I dont want to supply a specific value.

Here's what my desired graph looks like (similar to how a class teacher would draw this):
[Consider m=a]
[image: y=ax plot]

**Sympy**:

Tried doing this:
`sympy.plot(m*x,(x,0,10))`

but this shows the following error:
`ValueError: The same variable should be used in all univariate expressions being plotted.`

I cant really understand the error message, bit I am guessing it cant plot `m` as a (symbolic) constant in this case. Is it so? And in general, how can I do this?

**Matlab:**
Soon, I wanted to know if this is a limitation of sympy only, and thought maybe popular ones like matlab can do it? But with a bit of search on docs and SO, I couldnt find any. Both `plot` and `fplot` doesnt seem to cover this, they expect numerical values.

**Others:**
I am not acquainted with other plotting or CAS softwares, but it will be interesting to know if they support this out of the box

So, to repeat the main question, *how to draw similar graphs, preferably without managing the plotting code yourself ?*

The solution must be generic enough like `plot` to be applied to other equations.

[ The question was heavily edited from a sympy-specific question ]

Comment: Well you can't plot anything if you don't have the data, so why not just plot `y=x` and relabel the y axis labels?

Comment: @David Yes, that would be the simplest way to go about this, but I dont think you can handle a bit complex cases like non-linearity just with renaming the labels. Even for linear cases, say `y=a+m*x` - Now you also need to change the axis position. But I am not sure if those are the only 2 things I would need to handle. Also, you cant just replace every constant with 1 to draw the graph. For generic solution, we must honor the assumptions (like nonpositive=True as present in sympy) about them.

Answer (score 0):

Only for some functions with specific conditions you can plot thus in Maple. In Python (using matplotlib, sympy or any other packages) or Matlab you need to create code to manage that (assuming values and then replace ticks with literal ticks).

Comment: How to do this in Maple and what are the restrictions? Also, how to set the ticker in matplotlib? Please provide an example.

Comment: Do you need the plot from a equation variable (example, sympy equation) or can be a function with parameters (receive assumptions about a line with arguments)? Note: This is only possible for canonical forms of certain equations and evalueted each case (not a general mechanism). At the end of my work day, I can post the matplotlib code for plotting a line from assumption of symbolic constants.